# Radiator reservoir boiling and overflowing

Tags: subaru

I have a 2006 Subaru Forester that just had a ton of work done on it. New radiator, head gaskets, thermostat, water pump, and timing belt. Yesterday, after driving about an hour, i noticed a pool of antifreeze under the car. When i opened the hood, I saw the reservoir was VERY full, boiling, and spilling over. What could fix this?

Comment: Is the car overheating?

Comment: I'm too new to comment, but thats a lot of work you got done. Was it done by a friend or at an actual shop? First step to fixing it is making sure all that work was done correct. Try to hold the person responsible for their work.

Comment: please edit your question,was this work done in a repair shop? if it was the rapair might have been sub standard,there is a number of things that might have gone wrong but it sounds like a blown headgasket to me but there are other things that might have gone wrong too like the cooling system beeing overfilled but you say a pool of coolant so this is a bit less likely.